# Few basic questions about ionic bonding and batteries (lead)

Tags: electrochemistry, bond, atoms, electrons, ionic-compounds

I've got a few very very basic questions about ionic bonds and their role in batteries.

My assumptions (correct me if I'm wrong):

- Ionic bonds occur between a metal and a non-metal (the non-metal takes
  the metal's electron to fill its valence shell). Therefore the metal atoms are left with a positive charge and the non-metal a negative charge.
- Because of this, the atom tries to stabilise its ionised charge and tries to bond with the oppositely charged atom.
- Batteries take advantage of this chemical bonding to produce electricity.
- In a lead battery there is a PbO2, the electrolyte and Pb.
- The electrolyte is a non-metal and therefore it tries to fill it's valence shell with the electrons from PbO2. This creates an overall positive charge in the PbO2 and a negative charge in the solution.
- For some reason this negative charge is then transferred over to the Pb which gives it an overall negative charge.
- The Pb then wants to release this negative charge and pushes excess electrons which flow through a circuit to the PbO2 that is lacking electrons.

**This leaves me with a few questions:**

Why does the electrolyte solution choose to take electrons from PbO2 (I assume it has something to do with the O2)?

After the electrons are taken and there is a positive charge in the PbO2, and a negative charge in the solution, why don't they just bind together?

I thought ionic bonds occurred when an metal had it's electrons taken from it. How then does the Pb receive additional electrons from the non-metal solution?

If the Pb does want to receive the extra electrons, why would it instantly try to push them away through the circuit? I'd understand if the whole negatively charged atom was trying to be pulled to the positively charged PbO2 - but from what I've read it tries to push the excess electrons, not the atom - so why even receive the electron if it doesn't want it?

Comment: check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead%E2%80%93acid_battery and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redox